# Kobold2d: KKInput touch handling using touchPhases

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I don´t fully understand this, I am trying to set up touch handling using the default template, only difference I have made is that I delegate how to handle the touches to classs that implement the protocol. The problem is that the only `kTouchPhase` that works is `kTouchPhaseCancelled`.

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    if ([input isAnyTouchOnNode:self touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseAny])
    {

        CCLOG(@"Touch: beg=%d mov=%d sta=%d end=%d can=%d",
              [input isAnyTouchOnNode:self touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseBegan],
              [input isAnyTouchOnNode:self touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseMoved],
              [input isAnyTouchOnNode:self touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseStationary],
              [input isAnyTouchOnNode:self touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseEnded],
              [input isAnyTouchOnNode:self touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseCancelled]); 
    }

    CCDirector* director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    if (director.currentPlatformIsIOS)
    {
        [self gestureRecognition]; // Calls method pasted bellow

        if ([KKInput sharedInput].anyTouchEndedThisFrame)
        {
            CCLOG(@"anyTouchEndedThisFrame");
        }
    }
```

.->

```
-(void) gestureRecognition
{
    NSAssert(self.delegate != nil, @"Delegate must be non-nil");

    if (input.gestureTapRecognizedThisFrame)
    {
        [self.delegate moveObjectToNewPosition:input];
    }
```

And then the delegate which implements the protocol decides what to do in `moveObjectToNewPosition:`

```
-(void) moveObjectToNewPosition:(KKInput *)input
{
    //KKInput *input = [KKInput sharedInput];
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CGPoint touchLocation = [input locationOfAnyTouchInPhase:KKTouchPhaseBegan];
    [self touchesBegan:touchLocation];

}


- (void)touchesBegan: (CGPoint)touchLocation
{
    CCLOG(@"x: %f y: %f", touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
}
```

But the only touch phase that gives me coordinates is the `KKTouchPhaseCancelled` or `KKTouchPhaseAny`... What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

gesture recognizers capture touch events, specifically the tap recognizer will practically detect any touch (most touches are taps) and therefore you don't see any other touch events (phases) but cancel.

To fix this use the tap gesture's position property instead of location of any touch.

Comment: Ok so I changed the `if (input.gestureTapRecognizedThisFrame)` to ìnput.touchesAvailable`. Now I get the touchPhaseBegan in`[self touchesBegan:[input locationOfAnyTouchInPhase:KKTouchPhaseBegan]];` But if I do the same with KKTouchPhaseMoved and KKTouchPhaseEnded the result is unstable